# What is the Topology of the Iwasawa Manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let
$$
H=
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_1 & z_3 \\
0 &   1 & z_2 \\
0 &   0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}
:
z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}
\right\}
$$
be the complex Heisenberg group and denote by $G$ the subgroup of $H$ where the entries $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ are in the Gaussian integers.
Then $G$ acts on $H$ from the left and the quotient $W=H/G$ is a compact manifold with 6 real dimensions (3 complex dimensions, but $W$ is not Kähler).
$W$ is called *Iwasawa manifold*.

Note that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &   a & c \\
0 &   1 & b \\
0 &   0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_1 & z_3 \\
0 &   1 & z_2 \\
0 &   0 &   1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_1+a & z_3+a z_2+c \\
0 &   1 & z_2+b \\
0 &   0 &   1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e. every element in $W$ has exactly one representative with elements $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in [0,1)\times [0,1)i$.
It is mentioned e.g. in Daniel Huybrecht: Complex Geometry that $W$ is a non-trivial $2$-torus bundle over a $4$-torus (the non-triviality is checked by computing homology groups).

> Question 1:
>   Consider the map
>   $$\Phi: ([0,1]/_{\{0,1\}} \times [0,1]/_{\{0,1\}} i)^3 \rightarrow W, (z_1,z_2,z_3) \mapsto 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & z_1 & z_3 \\
> 0 &   1 & z_2 \\
> 0 &   0 &   1
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   This is a well-defined (i.e. $\Phi(0,0,0)=\Phi(1,0,0)=\Phi(0,1,0)=\dots$), bijective (statement about representatives for elements in $W$ above), continuous map.
>   Thus it is a homeomorphism.
>   However it can't be, because it has different homology groups.
>   What is the problem with my "homeomorphism"?

And

> Question 2:
>   What is a good way to define functions on $W$?
>   I was hoping to use above bijection, but there is something wrong with it, so it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I don't think your $\Phi$ is really well defined.

Comment: Why is that? Is there something more to check than $\Phi(0,0,0)=\Phi(1,0,0)=\dots$? This is true because $\Phi(1,0,0)=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix} \Phi (0,0,0)$, i.e. $\Phi(1,0,0)$ and $\Phi(0,0,0)$ are the same element in $W$.

Comment: There are many, many more identified points to check: your domain is a 6-dimensional cube with opposite faces identified. Try some points with $z_2 \ne 0.$

Comment: You're right, thank you for your answer. That answers question 1. Do you have a suggestion as to how to write down functions on $W$ (i.e. how to find left-invariant functions on $H$)? I am having trouble writing down *any* function on $W$ depending not just on $z_1$, $z_2$...